# Some vertices aren't visible when i go to edit mode from weight paint mode

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights, vertex-paint

When I am in weight paint mode and I want to create a vertex mask. I click tab and some of the mesh does not show the vertices.
[image: no vertices on entering edit mode]

I can hit alt-h to unhide but when i go back to weight paint mode and the vertex paint, it wont let me paint over them or show the vertices. how can i unhide those vertices? I'm fairly sure its not the subdivide sruface hiding them. its only on the arms some hair strands and the fingertips.

[image: no vertices shown in weight paint mode vertex mask]

Comment: Do you have a Mirror modifier on this object? Sometimes it messed up and flips the sides so your missing vertices might be on the other side. (The only solution I know to fix this is to apply the Mirror modifier, delete half of the mesh, and add a new Mirror modifier)

Comment: This works for the arms but i have the same problem with the hair. and I don't know how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

ok .....i have solved the problem , the problem was a bug.......i have uninstalled my blender 2.91 version ....and installed the 2.838 lts  version and this solved the problem .........lts version is better because they keep fix bugs